# All ways insert image into web page

Tags: html, css, image, web

How can we insert images (to be visible) into web pages?

- **img** tag with **src** attribute
- **background** attribute of the **body** tag (obsolete)
- **background** and **background-image** properties of the css
- **content** property of **:after** and **:before** css pseudo-elements
- html5 **canvas**
- inline **svg**

Are there other ways?

Answer (score 1):

- **border-image**: properties of the css